# I can click() a button, but not see innerHTML/length. What's up? (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, selenium, webdriver

Firstly I want to check if the modal exists, and if it  does click "continue". I can click continue but not check if the modal exists in the first place because when I run .length it returns undefined.
The div I am trying to get:

```
<div class="v--modal-box v--modal" style="top: 219px; left: 479px; width: 325px; height: auto;">
    <div class="v--modal-close-button absolute border-5 border-dark-grey-4 bg-slate-dark rounded-full z-50">
        <button class="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center text-grey hover:text-light-grey-1">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 22 22" class="fill-current">
                <path d="M22 2.59L19.41 0 11 8.41 2.59 0 0 2.59 8.41 11 0 19.41 2.59 22 11 13.59 19.41 22 22 19.41 13.59 11 22 2.59z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="p-4 md:p-6">
        <h3 class="heading text-center mb-2">Sign In</h3>
        <p class="text-center text-light-grey-1 text-sm md:text-base mb-6">Please sign in to start playing!</p>
        <a href="/login">
            <button data-v-4318eb75="" class="button-primary button-primary--green button-primary--large w-full">
                <svg data-v-4318eb75="" viewBox="0 0 22 22" class="w-26 w-26 mr-2">
                    <path data-v-4318eb75="" d="M11 0A10.93 10.93 0 0 0 .12 10.12L6 12.56A3 3 0 0 1 7.7 12h.17l2.6-3.8v-.04a4.11 4.11 0 1 1 4.11 4.15h-.1L10.78 15v.15a3.08 3.08 0 0 1-6.11.61L.49 14a10.89 10.89 0 0 0 21.39-3A11 11 0 0 0 11 0zM7 16.69l-1.34-.56a2.34 2.34 0 0 0 1.14 1.15 2.33 2.33 0 0 0 3-3.05 2.29 2.29 0 0 0-2.95-1.29l1.38.58a1.72 1.72 0 0 1 .92 2.24 1.69 1.69 0 0 1-2.15.93zm10.32-8.53a2.74 2.74 0 1 0-2.74 2.77 2.75 2.75 0 0 0 2.74-2.77zm-4.79 0a2.06 2.06 0 1 1 2.05 2.08 2.07 2.07 0 0 1-2.05-2.08z"></path>
                </svg>Sign In
                <!---->
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!---->
</div>
```

The code that I'm trying to run, which successfully clicks the button but returns undefined for the length. I have also tried .innerHTML and removed the .click event in case it fired of before getting the element, all with no good results..

```
const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require('selenium-webdriver');
var fs = require('fs');

launchSelenium();

async function launchSelenium(username, password) {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();

    await driver.get('https://csgoempire.com/');

    setTimeout(async function() {
        await driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        console.log(await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")).length);
        await (await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign In')]"))).click();
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: seems like you'd want .getAttribute("innerHTML") which would return a string you could run a length check on...

Comment: I dont want to get the length of a string, I want to check if the modal is currently opened :) would .getAttribute("length") maybe work?

Comment: I think you just want to check for something in the modal.... or visibility of.  Not sure why you want to check the length of anything.   I'm guessing the modal is also controlled via javascript, so use a WebDriverWait with the appropriate ExpectedCondition.  If the modal includes a clickable button just check for expected condition of "elementToBeClickable":  https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Comment: Could you give a appropiate example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
console.log(await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")).size());
```

Comment: I just get this error.. TypeError: driver.findElement(...).size is not a function

Comment: mmm... Maybe getSize()?   try writing **driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign In')]"))**  in the javascript console, and see there the available functions

Comment: getSize didn't work either.. Also, the javascript console can't help since driver is only available in my NodeJS script :(

Answer (score 0):

Well this might not be the absolute best solution, but this certainly works for me. Be aware that this is another example involving a welcome modal, however it's the same idea.

```
                    await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Welcome Back')]")).getAttribute("textContent")
                        .then(null, function (err) {
                            if (err.name === "NoSuchElementError") {
                                console.log("No Welcome Modal");
                            }
                        })
```